# Remove duplicates from view with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server

Using the following creates required view but need to remove any rows with duplicates in dbo.ORDRTXS.NO

```
SELECT     dbo.ORDRTRXS.REQ_DEL_DATE, dbo.ORDRTRXS.INV_NO, dbo.ORDRTRXS.PORDER_NO, dbo.ORDRTRXS.NO, dbo.ORDRHEAD.REP_CODE, 
                  dbo.SALEFILE.CUST_CODE, dbo.SALEFILE.CUST_NAME
FROM         dbo.SALEFILE INNER JOIN
                  dbo.ORDRTRXS ON dbo.SALEFILE.CUST_CODE = dbo.ORDRTRXS.DR_CODE INNER JOIN
                  dbo.ORDRHEAD ON dbo.ORDRTRXS.NO = dbo.ORDRHEAD.NO
```

Have tried using ROW_NUMBER but no luck

**ORDRTXS Table**

REQ_DEL_DATE | INV_NO | PORDER_NO | NO | DR_CODE

---

11/11/2016  |  12345 |  M123   | 1111  | A22

11/11/2016  |  12345 |  M123   | 1111  | A22

12/11/2016  |  12336 |  4455   | 1122  | Z11

**ORDERHEAD Table**

NO  |  REP_CODE

---

1111 |  AB

1111 |  AB

1122 | XY

**SALEFILE TABLE**

CUST_CODE | CUSTNAME

---

A22 | Customer One

Z11 | Customer Two

Required View

REQ_DEL_DATE | INV_NO | PORDER_NO | NO | DR_CODE | REP_CODE | CUSTNAME

---

11/11/2016 |   12345 |  M123  |   1111 | A22  |  AB  | Customer One

12/11/2016 |   12336 |  4455  |   1122 | Z11  |  XY  | Customer Two

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected output

Comment: What's the cardinalality between the tables?  Most likely you have a 1-M relationship between the tables causing M records to be returned when you only want 1.  So either your missing a join, need to add a distinct because the data making a record unique isn't a field you're returning in your data set.

Comment: What denotes a duplicate?  since each ordrtrxs seems to have it's own "NO" (number?) I don't see how you could have duplicates assuming it's part of the key.

Answer (score 0):

These are quick ways to eliminate the duplicates (Fixing what apperas to be  symptom, but not the real problem). I'd ask Why you're getting duplictes before using either of these answers.

1. It seems to me a SALEFILE contains customer details
2. ORDRHEAD is specific to a customer denoting a specific order for a customer
3. ORDRTRXS are the lines (items) specific to an order.

So... the question becomes is a duplicate occuring becuase multiple lines for the same item and po are occuring on the same order?  if so do you just need to "Sum" quantities? but that hides the Transaction Numbers...

```
SELECT OT.REQ_DEL_DATE
     , OT.INV_NO
     , OT.PORDER_NO
     , OT.NO
     , OH.REP_CODE
     , SF.CUST_CODE
     , SF.CUST_NAME
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CUST_CODE, CUST_NAME FROM dbo.SALEFILE)  SF
INNER JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT OT.REQ_DEL_DATE, OT.INV_NO, OT.PORDER_NO, OT.NO FROM dbo.ORDRTRXS) OT
  ON SF.CUST_CODE = OT.DR_CODE 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Rep_Code FROM dbo.ORDRHEAD) OH
  ON OT.NO = OH.NO

SELECT DISTINCT dbo.ORDRTRXS.REQ_DEL_DATE
              , dbo.ORDRTRXS.INV_NO
              , dbo.ORDRTRXS.PORDER_NO
              , dbo.ORDRTRXS.NO
              , dbo.ORDRHEAD.REP_CODE
              , dbo.SALEFILE.CUST_CODE
              , dbo.SALEFILE.CUST_NAME
FROM dbo.SALEFILE 
INNER JOIN dbo.ORDRTRXS 
  ON dbo.SALEFILE.CUST_CODE = dbo.ORDRTRXS.DR_CODE 
INNER JOIN dbo.ORDRHEAD ON dbo.ORDRTRXS.NO = dbo.ORDRHEAD.NO
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `DISTINCT` the `dbo.ORDRTRXS` table before joining.  Try the code below.

```
SELECT tr.REQ_DEL_DATE, tr.INV_NO, tr.PORDER_NO, tr.NO, oh.REP_CODE
    ,  sf.CUST_CODE, sf.CUST_NAME
FROM dbo.SALEFILE sf
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT REQ_DEL_DATE, INV_NO, PORDER_NO, NO, DR_CODE
    FROM dbo.ORDRTRXS
) tr ON tr.DR_CODE = sf.CUST_CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.ORDRHEAD oh ON oh.NO = tr.NO
```